# FancyVideo Light Box - Show on page load

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I am using fancyVideo light box (http://chadly.net/demos/video-lightbox.html) to have a light box and YouTube video show when a link is clicked.

See coding:

```
<div class="messageContainer" div id="watch_video">        
<div class="containerWarning3" style="color:#f96f00">
<center><h2>Watch <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVLt2dMKx6k&feature=aso"      rel="fancyvideo">this funny video</a> It is a good watch</h2></center>  
</div>
</div>
```

But I would now like to have the lightbox appear on page load ie so no need to click the Watch video link. Options? Ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to trigger the function via jQuery:

```
// .load() waits for EVERYTHING to load.
// .ready() waits for the document to be ready (i.e. not all the images have to be loaded).
// Swap them and see what happens.

$(document).load(function() {
  your_lightbox_trigger_function();
});
```

But that's assuming it's even possible to trigger a Flash video to play jQuery. I don't really know if it is

Comment: Mmm.. So what's the trigger function? rel="fancyvideo"??